# Is there any criterion when an interger solution of the equation $ax^2-by^2=c$ $(a,b,c\in\mathbb{N})$ exists?

Tags: number-theory

As title. In particular I'd like to know if it suffices that it's solvable in $\mathbb Z_p $ for $p$ being any prime number.

Comment: See, for example, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation2ndPowers.html

Comment: Get it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I do not see how the Mathworld link really addresses the question that was asked. The answer to the question of whether solvability in every $\mathbf Z_p$ implies solvability in $\mathbf Z$ is NO. For example, $x^2-37y^2=3$ is solvable in each $\mathbf Z_p$ but has no solution in $\mathbf Z$. I found this example mentioned in a comment by Kevin Buzzard to Felipe Voloch's answer at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/47442/diophantine-equation-with-no-integer-solutions-but-with-solutions-modulo-every

Comment: A beautiful counterexample. Thanks a lot